# How to use lib groups with bazel?

Tags: c++, linker, bazel

How can you set up cc_library to link libraries as part of a group? I'd like to write

```
cc_library(
  name = "abc",
  srcs = [
    ...
    libA.a,
    libB.a,
    ...
  ]
)
```

and have the linker put libA.a and libB.a together as a group

```
-Wl,--start-group libA.a libB.a -Wl,--end-group
```

I know there are lots of ways to misuse lib groups, but certain libraries like MKL require their components to be linked together like this.

Bazel doesn't look to have direct support for lib groups ([Issue #11593](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/11593)), but is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I had success doing something like this:

```
cc_library(
  name = "abc",
  srcs = [
    "libA.a",
    "libB.a",
  ],
  linkopts = [
    "-Wl,--start-group",
    "$(location libA.a)",
    "$(location libB.a)",
    "-Wl,--end-group",
  ],
)
```

Comment: I haven't gotten this approach to work. The problem is that libraries you list in source will already be linked so they end up being passed to the linker multiple times. For MKL (which has the circular dependencies), I still get the error.

Comment: However, I was able to make a modified version of the approach work by using additional_linker_inputs instead of srcs. https://bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp#cc_library.additional_linker_inputs